# Trouble Writing BeautifulSoup Output to File

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hello stackoverflow community!

I'm still learning the ins and outs of coding in Python, so please excuse my code that I am about to post.

I am currently trying to write a script that will scrape a list of the latest media torrents from http://kat.ph using BS4 and save it to a file. However, I am having trouble getting the output from BS4 to print to this file. When you open the text file, it's blank, but when you run the script in the terminal, it works just fine. Ultimately, I want to have python send the bs4 output in an email (which is where I originally ran into this problem and decided to see if I can write to .txt file).

I don't have the script that I made on my home computer at the moment, but I recreated another one where I did pretty much the same thing.

Any help/suggestions are much appreciated!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

#The goal of this script was to scrape the names of the latest media torrents and  write them to a text file.
#When I run the script on my computer, I can see the prompt give me the list of torrents just fine.
#When I try to write to a file or send an email, it doesn't print anything.

req = requests.get('http://kat.ph')

site = req.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(site) #Tried making this 'soup = str(BeautifulSoup(site)) to no avail.

def writingFunction():
    #I imported time module because I had my script display the time and date here.
    counter = 1
    for i in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'markeredBlock torType filmType'}):

        print str(counter) + '.' + ' ' + i.text
        counter = counter + 1

textFile = open('C:/python27/file.txt', 'a')
textFile.write(writingFunction()) #I've tried making this a str and I've also tried  assigning the function to a variable
textFile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

just write in the function, currently you are just printing the output:

```
def writing_function():
    with open('C:/python27/file.txt', 'a') as f:
        for ind, i in enumerate(soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'markedBlock torType filmType'}),1):
            f.write("{}. {}".format(ind, i.text.replace("\n","")))
```

`print str(counter) + '.' + ' ' + i.content.replace('\n', '')` is printing each line, you are not returning anything so `textFile.write(writingFunction())` is futile, just do your writing in the function.

If you don't want to hardcode the file name just pass it as a parameter:

```
def writing_function(my_file):
    with open(my_file, 'a') as f:
```

Using `enumerate` with a start index of `1` will do what your counter variable is doing.

There is no `.content` in bs4, it is `contents` which is a list, if you want the text use `i.text`.

Comment: the only way this is not printing is if your find_all finds nothing

Comment: You wouldn't believe me if I told you that didn't work. I followed what you said and used the enumerate function, but its still printing blanks.

Comment: Your find_all mus be  finding nothing so it makes sense that the file is empty,have you actually tried printing the contents of the findall to see what is there

Comment: You were right about one thing: I wasn't getting anything back from the find_all. I was mispelling one of the elements in the div tag. I corrected that and it prints to the file. The only problem is, its returning a bunch of "None" values.

Comment: then check before writing, `if i.content is not None:`

Comment: Yeah, its just printing a bunch of "None" values now.

Comment: then you are still finding nothing, `print i.content` in the for loop

Comment: find_all function works fine. I just tried writing it to a file using the str() method and no formatting and it writes with all of the tags in the file. However, when I try using the enumerate over the same thing, it returns "None"

Comment: what do you see when you print i in the loop, find_all returns a list so using enumerate  will work

Comment: I'm seeing the tags and everything inside of it when I print i

Comment: I just made a change to the code in the original post at the div tag referenced in find_all.

Comment: there is no such thing as content, it is contents and that is a list so it won't have a replace method

Comment: I feel like I'm getting closer and closer to figuring this out. I've fixed the i.content and made it i.text as well as my site variable is now req.text. I'll make the change to reflect it in the original post.

Comment: my code works, I have tested it, you don't need to change req.content. You are not still trying to run your function are you?

Comment: You should also stop changing the content in your question. The original question was asking why you were not getting anything in your file, that has been answered already if you have more questions you should ask another question